# Когда использовать aмперсанд, а когда GetAddressOf()

Tags: c++

В библиотеке *<wrl.h>* есть класс **ComPtr<>();**

В ней перегружен aмперсанд, а так же есть метод **GetAddressOf()**

```
ComPtr<...> pVar;
&pVar / pVar.GetAddressOf();
```

Когда использовать **&**, а когда **GetAddressOf()** и чем они отличаются?

Comment: [Этот же вопрос на английском языке с ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006988/winrt-c-comptr-getaddressof-vs)

Comment: А чем описание разницы из документации не устраивает?

Comment: @user7860670 "Освобождает интерфейс, а затем извлекает адрес объекта ComPtr." Почему в некоторых местах нам это не мешает, например, при создании буфера `wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> pConstantBuffer; pDevice->CreateBuffer(..., ..., &pConstantBuffer)` Вот например почему тут можно освободить (как я понимаю освободить - это очистить данные), А вот тут `pContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0u, 1u, pConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf());` Уже нельзя

Comment: В первом случае указатель нулевой и при вызове функции ему присваивается значение (с передачей владения). Если бы он был не нулевой и не освобожден заранее, то произошла бы учетка. Во втором происходит получения указателя, как на массив из одного элемента-указателя с разделением владения.